# React.js : Submitting the form on checking errors and adding new user

Tags: reactjs

I have set the errors and I'm checking if there are no errors it should redirect to 'userslist' page but on submitting the form the event is not triggered. How can I redirect to the 'userslist' page when a new user is created? I'm not getting where I'm going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Here's the code :

```
  import {useState,useEffect,useContext} from 'react'
  import { GlobalContext } from './context/GlobalState'
  import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
  import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'
  import axios from 'axios'
  const useForm=(validate)=>{
  const { addUser } = useContext(GlobalContext)
  const history = useHistory()
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    fullname: '',
    fullnameError:'',
    birthdate: new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '/'),
    address: '',
    gender: '',
    college: [],
    hobbies:[]
  })
  const [errors,setErrors]=useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
   async function fetchData(name) {
   const response = await axios.get(`http://universities.hipolabs.com/search`, {
    params: { name }
   }
   )
   console.log(response.data)
   setValues({...values, college: response.data })
  }
  fetchData('Middle')
 }, [])
 const handleChange = e => {
 setValues({
  ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value
 })
}
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault() 
  if(errors){
    setErrors(validate(values))
  }
  else{
    newUser()
  }
 }

const newUser = ()=>{
  const newwUser={
  id: uuid(),
  fullname: values.fullname,
  birthdate: values.birthdate,
  address: values.address,
  college: values.college,
  gender: values.gender,
  hobbies: values.hobbies
 }
 addUser(newwUser)
 history.push('/userslist')
 }
 return {handleChange,values,handleSubmit,errors}
 }

  export default useForm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement will always return true because you have set the error state to an empty object. Passing an empty object like this:

```
 if({})
```

...will return true. Instead you need to check if the error state object is NOT empty, like this:

```
if (Object.keys(errors).length !== 0)
```

Comment: I read your question too quickly, I’ve just looked at it  again and I don’t understand why you are checking for errors in the state property, because I can’t see anywhere in the code where you are setting any errors. You’ve set the initial state to an empty object, then you are checking if there are any errors, which there won’t be, because it’s an empty object, and then setting them??? I think you need to reevaluate the flow